# How to make Chrome forget about previous tabs in same "session"

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser-tabs

When I close the whole Chrome window and reopen it again, all my (often many) tabs get automatically restored. What I am looking for is a solution that I only get a single blank tab when I restart Chrome.

**What I already did:**
I set "Open new tab page" as my Chrome startup option

**What causes the problem:**
I use Chrome not only for browsing websites, but also as an "app launcher" for the Google Apps (Gmail, Calendar, Drive, etc.) as a "standalone" app in a separate window. When I close all my other open windows using the Chrome engine, I get the wanted empty tab on a Chrome browser restart. But I would like to be able to leave the other Google Apps running in their separate window because I use them a lot and they would need quite some time to load if I would close them on a regular basis (especially Gmail). So, I guess I am looking for some way that Google chrome ignores the other separate windows and just kills all the previously opened tabs when I close and open the Chrome browser again.

[image]

There are my current Chrome settings (open new tab page):

[image]

Comment: What do you have in Chrome *Settings > On Startup*? Perhaps you should try other settings.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my settings in my question

Comment: Check in Settings, System, if the option "Continue running background apps when google chrome is closed" is unchecked.

Comment: Great idea! However, it does not influence the situation with the tabs, unfortunately... - having Gmail and other apps open as a separat app/window does still also count as an open chrome session...

Comment: Idea: Run the Apps in a sandbox, isolated from the normal desktop, using a tool such as the free [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/).

Comment: That could work, however, I am not feeling comfortable using a sandbox (I am to less of a hardcore user to go into that) - however, I would appreciate if Google would offer this as an option when creating the shortcut. Currently they only give the option to open in a new window, but open in sandbox would be a great idea

Comment: Sandboxie isn't that hard to understand. If you start the app from a shortcut, it's possible to modify the shortcut to launch directly into the sandbox.

Comment: What about my login state? Would I still be logged in with my Google account?

Comment: Yes, modifications of disk and registry are persistent inside the sandbox.

Comment: Is it also possible to use multiple (virtual) Windows desktops instead? Or the native sandbox from Windows?

Comment: The Windows sandbox is not persistent. Virtual desktops are not separated.

Comment: OK, thank you - would it perhaps also be possible to make Chrome close all tabs on window close? That would solve the problem also...